# What is the gist of the equations on Alejandro Guijarro's "2/14" "Momentum" blackboard?

Tags: soft-question, de-sitter-spacetime

The artist [Alejandro Guijarro](http://www.alejandroguijarro.com/) has an exhibit of photographs of a variety of blackboards with physics equations, drawings and text on them, as covered at [Quantum Chaos on Display in Top Physicists’ Chalk Scrawls | Raw File | WIRED](http://www.wired.com/2012/12/the-fundamental-uncertainty-of-photography/)

What is the one in the first closeup photograph (numbered "2/14") about?  The circled text "non SUSY" suggests that at least one of the topics is [Supersymmetry (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry), but what is the gist of it?

For clarity, this question is about the blackboard in the first closeup image on the [Momentum exhibit web site](http://www.alejandroguijarro.com/ongoing/blackboards/), labeled "2/14".

[image]

Caption: [$\uparrow$ Click image to enlarge it](http://www.wired.com/images_blogs/rawfile/2013/01/01.jpg).

For example, the equation in the upper left starts with

> $T_{ds} \sim 1/R$

For extra credit - where is the blackboard / who wrote on it / etc?

(Note that I am also interested in the other blackboards, and suggest separate questions here for each of those.  There is some commentary on some of the others at
[The Beautiful Blackboards at Quantum Physics Labs | MetaFilter](http://www.metafilter.com/121363/The-Beautiful-Blackboards-at-Quantum-Physics-Labs))

Comment: Give the subscripts, it's probably the temperature in [de Sitter space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space). I don't know whether $R$ represents some scale radius or if it is the [Ricci scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature). I also could be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full statement seems to be:

$T_{dS}\sim\frac{1}{R}\sim \sqrt\Lambda \implies non-SUSY$

In a [de Sitter universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe), that the temperature (at the horizon) is inversely proportional to radius (distance to horizon) and proportional to the square root of the [cosmological constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant) implies breaking of super symmetry.

See for example [Temperature at horizon in de Sitter spacetime](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0404010v2.pdf)

Under that statement is:

$S_{dS}\sim(M_PR)^2\sim1/\Lambda \implies$ **Quantum System w/FINITE # of STATES**

In a de Sitter universe, that entropy (of the horizon) is proportional to the square of the product of the Planck mass and radius (distance to horizon) and inversely proportional to the cosmological constant implies a quantum system with a finite number of states.

Below the word "STATES" is boxed-off section of the board with the title "Static Patch".
A [general relativity metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28general_relativity%29) for a static patch of de Sitter space is written.  Compare to Equation 3.1 of [Towards a quantum theory of de Sitter space](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0609062v1.pdf).

To the left of this box is:

e-//particles & BHs
unstable in dS

Charged particles and black holes are unstable in de Sitter space.  Near the bottom left, using the same abbreviations, it is stated that charged particles and black holes are excitations of de Sitter space.

Comment: Interesting!  Does that fit in with the rest of the blackboard?  Got any links to help understand that more?

Comment: here's a link for the temperature-radius relationship: http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept02/Padmanabhan/Pad10_3.html The link uses "1/H" instead of "R". $T = H/ 2\pi $, where $H = 1/R$

Comment: @nealmcb I added a "de Sitter universe" link to the answer, that mentions the "proportional to the square root of the cosmological constant" aspect, but again in terms of H instead of 1/R.

Comment: @nealmcb and references for the implication that super symmetry is broken: http://people.physik.hu-berlin.de/~ahoop/10-petrini.pdf and http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0102309.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: Odd - I thought I submitted an edit to make this a comprehensive answer (including some of Dave's comments, and the text of my own answer) that I could accept and thus give @DavePhD credit, but I don't see any trace of it now. Did it get rejected for some reason?

Comment: @nealmcb Yes you did submit the edit.  I got a message that it was rejected as a radical change.  I would have also rejected such an edit as a radical change. I just want to keep my answer the partial answer that it is, maybe add to it eventually.  I don't need any credit.

Comment: Got it. Odd that I didn't hear about the rejection.  And thanks for the updates!

Answer (score 1):

According to commentator "bn" at [The Chalkboards of Quantum Mechanics Professors (via Wired)](http://www.brachiolopemedia.com/forum/index.php?topic=324.0), this one is mostly about holography, how much information can be contained on a 2-D screen of a certain size.  The diamonds are referring to domains of causal dependence.  The square brackets are commutator brackets ([Canonical commutation relation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation)), and the script L's are angular momentum operations.

There is a bit more detail at that link.  If someone else who actually understands this stuff can flesh this out more, I'd love it.